# Regex fails on new line

Tags: php, regex

I have an regex expresion which is like this

```
preg_match("/^\\s*(insert|delete|update|replace|create|drop|alter|use) /i",$query)
```

This is a part of a pretty old function which is responsible for allmost all of the transactions on our site that we maintain (it is like 8 years old at min...)

Imagine my suprice when this query failed te test on this regex....

```
"DELETE
                    FROM KursSmer 
                    WHERE   IDKurs = '523' AND
                            IDSmer = '50' AND
                            IDSkolskaGodina = '1' AND
                            JeObavezan = '0'"
```

It took me about 1h to get the nasty fella... but i did it... there was a \n line element on the end of the first row just next to DELETE word... like `DELETE\n`

Now, I am left wondering if this can be corrected?

Comment: You already use `\s*` earlier in the regex. Do you know what it means?

Comment: I hope you're not using this regex to prevent/detect sql injection...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `m` modifier for multiple lines.

```
preg_match("/^\\s*(insert|delete|update|replace|create|drop|alter|use) /im",$query)
```

[Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: Thank you :), you would not belive that this regex was at core db class for over 8 years and none broke it untill now... untill i mengeled with it :P